# Changing value of Linked List without flexiblility in parameters

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I have an assignment. I was provided with a function declaration that I cannot modify.

The function declaration is `void Insert (Item x, int p, List *L);` where I am supposed to change the values of the linked list struct, L.

Now, the code that invokes that method in my main function is

```
struct List *L = malloc(sizeof(List));   
Insert(x,p,L);
```

How would I change my code so I can pass the address of the struct List instead of making another copy of it?

Like I said, I cannot change the function declaration at all.

`/*********************************************************************
 * FUNCTION NAME: Insert
 * PURPOSE: Inserts an Item in a List.
 * ARGUMENTS: . The Item to be inserted (Item)
 *            . The position in the List
 *              where the Item should be inserted in (int) 
 *            . The address of the List (List *L)
 * REQUIRES (preconditions):
 *            . The position should be a nonnegative integer
 *              not greater than the size of the List.
 *            . The List should not be full.
 * ENSURES: . Empty will return false (0).
 *          . Size will return the first integer greater
 *            than the size of the List before the call.
 *          . Peek in the same position will find
 *            the Item that was inserted.
 *********************************************************************/
extern void Insert (Item X, int position, List *L);`

What I tried that didn't work was
`head->next = L; //changing the next item in list to L
L = head; //changing the address of L so it remains the head of the list`

Comment: That's what your code does. What's the problem?

Comment: `L` is a pointer that contains the address of a `struct List`.

Comment: Just want to point out that `void Insert (struct List *L, int x);` is not a header file. It is a function declaration.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_functions.htm

Comment: When I run the program the Insert does not change the value of L that's in the main function. Somehow it make changes to a temporary copy of L, then when I access the list in the main function L is not changed.   I know Insert is a function declearation. It's in the header file that I can't change.

Comment: @AlanCai Could you please add the function definition for `Insert()`?

Comment: C does not support _methods_. That is a _function_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
void Insert (Item x, int p, List *L) {
    struct List newnode, last = *L;
    newnode = (struct List)malloc(sizeof(struct List));
    newnode->item = x;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    if (last == NULL){
        if (p == 0) { *L = newnode; }//first node
        else { printf("List is empty and index %d does not exist", p); }
    } else if (p == 0) {
        newnode->next = *L;
        *L = newnode;
    }
    else{
        int counter = 0;
        while (1) {
            if (counter == p) {
                newnode->next = last->next; 
                last->next = newnode;
                break;
            }
            last = last->next;
            counter++;
            if (last->next == NULL && counter != p){ break; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but it doesn't account for inserting the item at the beginning of the list, which is what I ran into problems with. I did newnode->next = last; last = newnode; It prints correct value inside the function but the value of last is unmodified in the main function.

Comment: I added one more condition  to handle that and corrected some typos

Answer (score 0):

You might want to review the differences (or similarities) between addresses, pointers in C because the answer to your question is that you are already passing the address of your struct List.

I will try and explain a bit. malloc() returns a memory address, AKA a pointer, which is denoted by the * symbol in `struct List *L`. When I read this line in my head, I would say "L contains a pointer to a struct List object" or "L contains the memory address of a struct List object".

So in that case, when you write `Insert(L, x)` you are already passing a pointer to your struct List object. And no other copy is being made. So any actions you perform inside of your `Insert()` function will be acting on the original list.

The only exception to this rule is if you try to reassign L in your insert method, like this:

```
void Insert(struct List* L, int x) {
    L = NULL; // or L = malloc(sizeof(struct List));
}
```

This will not do what you might expect, but the reason for that is more complicated and something you probably don't need to know for the time being.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but I still don't understand why it is that when I modify the pointer, it's value changes in the function but remains the same in the main function.

Comment: Eg: When I do head->next = L; L=head; the address of L is not changed in main function.

Comment: I'm sure you have learnt why you cannot change a simple variable in a function. E.g. why this swap function doesn't work? `swap(int x, int y) { int tmp = x; x = y; y = tmp; }` This doesn't work because x and y are passed into the function by value, meaning they are copies. You may have been told the way to get around this is to use pointers. E.g. `swap(int* x, int* y) { int tmp = *x; *x = *y; *y = tmp; }` which is true, but they usually forget to explain that the pointers (the `int*x`) are still passed by value. Which is why changing L in the insert function doesn't work. Same concept.

Comment: But I'm assigning the next pointer inside the head to L, then changing the address of L to head so L can be the head of the list in main. L and head are both structs that contains a pointer inside

Comment: Yep, you can't do that. Specifically, you cannot modify L in the function. Any line that begins with this `L = ` will not behave as you expect.

Comment: I can tell you now that you need to insert the new item at the end of the list, not at the beginning, and that the insert function requires a non-null list to start with.

Comment: I malloc the list. I have to insert the items in positions specified, and the first 2 items needed to be inserted to the front.

Answer (score 0):

There are irregularities with your function declarations.

Your code suggests that you have a function with the following signature :

```
void Insert (struct List *L, int x);
```

The header file that you have linked uses a function insert with this signature :

```
extern void Insert (Item X, int position, List *L);
```

Note the additional parameter `Item X`.

There isn't much to go on since you haven't showed us much of your code, but I would suggest taking a look at your missing parameter.

Comment: @AlanCai In that case, if your parameter `x` is the position, what are you inserting exactly in your list? Please show the implementation of Insert()

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

> How would I change my code so I can pass the address of the struct List instead of making another copy of it?

You are already doing it: `void Insert (Item x, int p, List *L);` takes **pointer** to List structure, not structure itself, so you are not copying it.

Secondly:

> What I tried that didn't work was head->next = L; //changing the next item in list to L
>   **L = head;** //changing the address of L so it remains the head of the list

It won't work. Inside `Insert` function L is value of pointer to List. So if you change this value inside the function it won't be change outside, as value of L is passed by copy. Only changes to `*L` will be seen, as they will not change value of `L` itself, but value of what `L` is pointing to.

I can assure you, that no `L =` is needed inside `Insert` function to complete this task.

Moreover take good look at prerequisites - they should discribe situations, which you do not need to trouble yourself with (probably, I don't know person which created this task, but I would understand it this way) - meaning, if user doesn't comply to them, it's users own fault, anything bad can happen.